# Distributing Identical Objects

Tags: combinatorics

I have 15 identical objects to distribute to 4 people,
two people get atleast one each while the other two remaing people get none.

My guess at the answer,
C(13+2-1, 13) * 3

Would this be right? I hand out two of the
objects to two people the distribute the rest multiplied by 
how many ways two people can have the rest and the rest can have none.

Comment: I'm sorry, but shouldn't it read as "two get at least one each??"

Comment: YES you're right!

Answer (score 0):

Choose the two people to get objects.  There are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to do that.

Each of the two people (A and B) gets at least one object, thereby leaving 13 objects yet to distribute.  It could be 13 to A and 0 to B, or 12 to A and 1 to B or ... or 0 to A and 13 to B.  There are 14 such conditions.

So $6 \cdot 14 = 84$.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer should look like $^4C_2*^{13+2-1}C_{2-1}$

That is, selecting two people to be given the objects. Then distributing $13$ objects among two of them such that getting $0$ is allowed

Comment: I'm sorry can you please elaborate?

Comment: To distribute $n$ identical objects among $m$ people, we do $^{n+m-1}C_{m-1}$ @user203042